# Is there anyway to make a lesser impact on my database with this request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, refactoring

For the analytics of my site, I'm required to extract the 4 states of my users.

```
@members   = list.members.where(enterprise_registration_id: registration.id)
# This pulls roughly 10,0000 records.. Which is evidently a huge data pull for Rails
# Member Load (155.5ms)

@invited            = @members.where("user_id is null")
# Member Load (21.6ms)
@not_started        = @members.where("enterprise_members.id not in (select enterprise_member_id from quizzes where quizzes.section_id IN (?)) AND enterprise_members.user_id in (select id from users)", @sections.map(&:id) )
# Member Load (82.9ms)
@in_progress        = @members.joins(:quizzes).where('quizzes.section_id IN (?) and (quizzes.completed is null or quizzes.completed = ?)', @sections.map(&:id), false).group("enterprise_members.id HAVING count(quizzes.id) > 0")
# Member Load (28.5ms)
@completes          = Quiz.where(enterprise_member_id: registration.members, section_id: @sections.map(&:id)).completed
# Quiz Load (138.9ms)
```

The operation returns a 503 meaning my app gives up on the request. Any ideas how I can refactor this code to run faster? Maybe by better joins syntax? I'm curious how sites with larger datasets accomplish what seems like such trivial DB calls.

Comment: Is `@sections` a relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your ideas. I basically did what everyone said. I added indexes, resorted how I called everything, but the major difference was using the `pluck` method.. Here's my new stats :

```
  @alt_members   = list.members.pluck :id # 23ms
  if list.course.sections.tests.present? && @sections = list.course.sections.tests
    @quiz_member_ids    = Quiz.where(section_id: @sections.map(&:id)).pluck(:enterprise_member_id) # 8.5ms
    @invited            = list.members.count('user_id is null') # 12.5ms
    @not_started        = ( @alt_members - ( @alt_members & @quiz_member_ids ).count #0ms
    @in_progress        = ( @alt_members & @quiz_member_ids ).count # 0ms
    @completes          = ( @alt_members & Quiz.where(section_id: @sections.map(&:id), completed: true).pluck(:enterprise_member_id) ).count # 9.7ms
    @question_count     = Quiz.where(section_id: @sections.map(&:id), completed: true).limit(5).map{|quiz|quiz.answers.count}.max # 3.5ms
```

Answer (score 1):

**THIRD QUERY:**

I unfortunately don't know ruby on rails, but from a postgresql perspective, changing your "not in" to a left outer join should make it a little faster:

Your code:

```
enterprise_members.id not in (select enterprise_member_id from quizzes where quizzes.section_id IN (?)) AND enterprise_members.user_id in (select id from users)", @sections.map(&:id) )
```

Better version (in SQL):

```
select blah
  from enterprise_members em
  left outer join quizzes q on q.enterprise_member_id = em.id
  join users u on u.id = q.enterprise_member_id
 where quizzes.section_id in (?)
   and q.enterprise_member_id is null
```

Based on my understanding this will allow postgres to sort both the enterprise_members table and the quizzes and do a hash join.  This is better than when it will do now.  Right now it finds everything in the quizzes subquery, brings it into memory, and *then* tries to match it to enterprise_members.

**FIRST QUERY:**

You could also create a partial index on user_id for your first query.  This will be especially good if there are a relatively small number of user_ids that are null in a large table.  Partial index creation:

```
CREATE INDEX user_id_null_ix ON enterprise_members (user_id)
WHERE (user_id is null);
```

Anytime you query enterprise_members with something that matches the index's where clause, the partial index can be used and quickly limit the rows returned.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-partial.html for more info.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is your indexes.  Check your rails logs (or check the console in development mode) and copy the queries to your db tool.  Slap an "Explain" in front of the query and it will give you a breakdown.  From here you can see what indexes you need to optimize the query.

For a quick pass, you should at least have these in your schema,

1. enterprise_members: needs an index on enterprise_member_id
2. members: user_id
3. quizes: section_id

Answer (score 1):

As someone else posted definitely look into adding indexes if needed. Some of how to refactor depends on what exactly you are trying to do with all these records. For the @members query, what are you using the @members records for? Do you really need to retrieve all attributes for every member record? If you are not using every attribute, I suggest only getting the attributes that you actually use for something, .pluck usage could be warranted. 3rd and 4th queries, look fishy. I assume you've run the queries in a console? Again not sure what the queries are being used for but I'll toss in that it is often useful to write raw sql first and query on the db first. Then, you can apply your findings to rewriting activerecord queries.

What is the .completed tagged on the end? Is it supposed to be there? only thing I found close in the rails api is .completed? If it is a custom method definitely look into it. You potentially also have an use case for scopes.